# nth child even/odd selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to make the backgrounds with a light green have dark text and the background with dark green have white text, but for some reason the a:nth-child(odd) selector is targeting all the anchors in the list. Any ideas? Made a Pen for it too:
http://codepen.io/plloyd11/pen/zfcED

HTML:

```
<div id="commercialNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/auditcomplete">Audit Complete</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/commercial-bed-bug-program">Bed Bug Elite</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/bird-select">Bird Select</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/german-cockroach-program-overview">Cockroach Clean Out Program</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/ecoready">EcoReady</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/systematic-fly-elimination">SFE Fly Program</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/healthcare">Healthcare</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/hotels-and-resorts">Hotels and Resorts</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/inspected-facilities">Inspected Facilities</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/mosquito-direct">MosquitoDirect</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/commercial-product-lines">Product Lines</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/property-management">Property Management</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/restaurants">Restaurants</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/termites-commercial">Termites</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#commercialNav li {
list-style-type: none;  
}

#commercialNav a {
color: #fff;
text-decoration:none;
}

#commercialNav li:nth-child(even) {
background:#215034;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
}

#commercialNav li:nth-child(odd) {
background:#BACDBA;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
}
#commercialNav a:nth-child(odd) {
color:#215034;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the last rule to:

```
#commercialNav li:nth-child(odd) a{
    color:#215034;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6MhTq/)**

The anchors aren't children of the #commercialNav div (although they are descendants), so that particular selector you were trying won't work. If you didn't have the list items in there then the rule would work, but since the anchors aren't sibling of each other, you need to use the selectors as I show above.

Answer (score 2):

nth-child(odd) finds the elements that are odd children of their *immediate* parent. Each of your a tags is the first child of their parents (the li's).

I think you want:

```
#commercialNav li:nth-child(odd) a
```

Answer (score 0):

just try this:

```
#commercialNav li:nth-child(odd) a{
    color:#215034;
}
```